# R Tidy correlogram by group

Tags: r, tidy, r-corrplot

I would like to use a tidy approach to produce correlograms by group.
My attempt with `iris` and libraries `dplyr` and `corrplot`:

```
library(corrplot)
library(dplyr)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_map(~ corrplot::corrplot(cor(.x,use = "complete.obs"),tl.cex=0.7,title =""))
```

It works but I would like to add the Species name on each plot.
Also, any other tidy approaches/ functions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cur_group()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(corrplot)
out <- iris %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>%
       summarise(outr = list( corrplot::corrplot(cor(cur_data(),
            use = "complete.obs"),tl.cex=0.7,title = cur_group()[[1]])))
```

---

Or if we are using `group_map`, the `.keep = FALSE` by default.  Specify it as `TRUE` and extract the group element

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_map(~ corrplot::corrplot(cor(select(.x, where(is.numeric)),
      use = "complete.obs"),tl.cex=0.7,title = first(.x$Species)), .keep = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `map` approach with `imap` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  imap(~corrplot::corrplot(cor(.x[-5],use ="complete.obs"),tl.cex=0.7,title =.y))
```